# Proving that $X_{(1)}$ is a completely sufficient statistic and that $S^2$ is ancillary.

Tags: statistics

Given that $f_{\mu}(x) = e^{-(x-\mu)},  x \in (\mu, \infty)$,

I need to show that $X_{(1)}$ is a completely sufficient statistic.

I know that for the statistic to be complete it needs to satisfy:

$$E_\mu(g(X_{(1)})) = \int_\mu^\infty g(y)f_{X_{(1)}}(y) \, dy = 0 \text{ for all } \mu$$

I know that $f_{X_{(1)}}(y) = nf_{\mu}(y)[1-F_{\mu}(y)]^{n-1}$

but how do I find the function $g$?

I honestly have no idea.

Then I need to use Basu's theorem to show that $X_{(1)}$ and $S^2$ are independent, and I know to do that by showing that $S^2$ is ancillary. How do I show this as well?

Comment: Your integral should be $\displaystyle \int_\mu^\infty g(y) f_{X_{(1)}}(y) \, dy.  \qquad $

Comment: thanks I completely missed that

Comment: What do you have to do to show completeness? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/427364/119261.

Comment: You wrote: $\text{“}$I know that for the statistic to be complete it needs to satisfy: $$E_\mu(g(X_{(1)})) = \int_\mu^\infty g(y)f_{X_{(1)}}(y) \, dy = 0 \text{ for all } \mu \text{''}$$ That is a confused way of expressing it.  What is to be proved is that the ONLY function $g$ for which
$$ \operatorname E_\mu(g(X_{(1)})) = \int_\mu^\infty g(y) f_{X_{(1)}} (y) \,dy = 0 $$ is the identically $0$ function. The question of "how to find $g(X_{(1)}),$" as if $g$ were some particular specified function, does not arise. $\qquad$

Comment: You don't define $S^2$. If it is the sample variance, then note that $\sum(X_i-\overline X)^2=\sum(Y_i-\overline Y)^2$ where $Y_i=X_i-\mu$, whose distribution is free of $\mu$.